# Developing Puppet locally using Vagrant + Docker

Tags: docker, vagrant, puppet, devops

I'm trying to come up with a strategy for developing puppet roles and profiles locally. Ideally I want a self-contained git repo that has everything needed to stand up the master as well as a test node(s) that roles under development can be applied to and validated.

My current solution is to use docker-compose to [launch a local puppet master](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-in-docker-examples/tree/master/compose). This maps the local code folder on my dev machine to the /etc/puppet/code volume on the master container. For the test nodes part I'm thinking I can use vagrant with a puppet provisioner. The reason I selected vagrant (as opposed to just running docker agent images is that some of my roles apply to windows machines. This seems like the best option for supporting both windows and linux puppet roles.

My struggle at the moment is figuring out how to bridge the two virtual networks (vagrant to docker). I can sort of fake it out by exporting the puppet master ports (8140) to the host and then pointing my vagrant provisioner at the host. The problem with this approach is that I have to use the gateway IP assigned to the vagrant guest (corresponds to the host) and I'm not confident that solution is going to be stable across my team.

I'm looking for suggestions on...

- does this seem like a viable/correct approach for accomplishing my goal?
- how can I cleanly combine these two solutions (docker + vagrant)
- have I missed some existing standard practice that already solves this problem?

Here is [the github repo](https://github.com/markjgardner/LocalPuppetDevelopment) with my work so far. Feel free to submit a PR with any suggestions.

Comment: Why do you want to use Docker in this case? Also, why not instead write tests for the roles and modules using RSpec and Beaker / Test Kitchen / Serverspec? These libraries already exist to help locally develop Puppet modules and test them in VMs. IN the case of Serverspec, there is a Docker provider if you wanted to run the tests in a container instead of a VM.

Comment: It's not just about unit testing. I struggle with the accepted CI/CD model for puppet in general. Our shop currently does puppet development on a single puppet master bound to a single git repository. There are branches within the git repo that map to environments on the master, but it's all still deploying to our "production" master. I don't like that, it feels wrong. I want to treat my puppet development exactly like I would an application. Deploy it to separate environments for validation before I put it in production. Unit tests are definitely part of that but not the entire solution.

Comment: OK, your questions are pretty broad in their current form. There are likely many ways to answer this. You might try to clarify and maybe center on a specific problem you are struggling with.

Answer (score 1):

What you're thinking about **is** a viable solution. There's a lot of ways to get this done, but since you were asking about other ways I've done this with `puppet apply` and Docker directly. I wrote an old wiki post about it [here](https://github.com/frozenfoxx/frozenfoxx.github.io/wiki/Puppet-Testing-with-Docker), I was using Puppet 4 at the time so it's still pretty relevant.

Essentially what you're going to do is make a self-contained testing repo, run r10k, and mount those into a temporary machine.

- make a workshop repo (I've provided a [sample](https://github.com/frozenfoxx/puppet-roles-profiles))
- give it a base branch (I pick `production` since that's a known
  Puppet default).
- make a new branch to commit your roles and profiles to for testing the module.
- Adjust the `default` target in `site.pp` to include that role.
- run `r10k deploy environment -pv` with the `r10k.yaml` set to that workshop repo.

  - Why? This way you can ensure that ALL modules in the
    `Puppetfile` get pulled and your workshop looks as close to whatever
    testing environment you wanted to use.
- pull a Docker container with the Puppet toolkit

  - I made an old one, Puppetlabs maintains an official one, you can make your own, doesn't really matter
- bind mount the unrolled directory into it, give it a `puppet apply /etc/puppet/code/environments/[branch]/manifests/site.pp` and see what happens.

Because you're interested in using Vagrant you can likely just have the Vagrant image do the `r10k deploy` and run the Docker command all-in-one. That'd get you a complete pushbutton setup.

As noted there's a *lot* of ways to get this done, but that's one that's worked for me in the past. Sometimes it's a lot easier to see this stuff interactively instead of coding around Beaker/Kitchen/serverspec stuff.